# Data augmentation before the test/train split on a small dataset

Tags: neural-networks, train-test-split

First of all im working with a project that is not mine and cointains 0 explanatios about why things were done and I fear some of them are just mistakes.

I found that for the trainig of a convolutional neural network with a from a pretrained model on the detectron2 platform, the split of train and test sets was done after the data augmentaion, so some images are duplicated in both of the sets with different augmentations.

He only had 10 images for the training, so I guess he wanted to expand the dataset but im not sure about the method.

Comment: 10 samples would not be enough to run linear regression with one feature parameter reliably. You need more data. Data augmentation won't help here.

Comment: @Tim I know, thats why im redoing it now that we have way more data. My main concern now is the repetition of images, not the amount.

Comment: If you have more data now, why not run it from scratch on the new data? I'd guess that the results obtained on 10 samples were rubbish, so you probably should not care about this.

Comment: @Tim i will run it from 0, but i want to know if i can use the original pipeline instead of starting a project from scratch